# What is the created time in docker images command?

Tags: docker

What is the CREATED time exactly when you give this command?

> docker images
>   [image]

It gives the time like 3 months ago, or 9 days ago.

Is it the time it was uploaded to docker hub?

Even for the locally created images, it shows like 15 minutes ago, while I had created just a minute ago.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It should be the date of the latest `docker build` run by the image owner, as defined in the [`image/image.go`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/131e2bf12b2e1b3ee31b628a501f96bbb901f479/image/image.go#L28-L29) file, which can be found in the container once the image has been run.

You can inspect low-level image info to see its exact value with:

```
docker inspect -f '{{.Created}}' hello-world
```

where 'hello-world' is the name of your image.

If you are in a VM, the timestamp might not be precise for local images, as your VM clock might not be precisely synchronized (by typing '`date`', I see mine is synchronized, but on UTC: one hour shift).

Comment: For something that can be quite useful, there's no official mention of what *exactly* `Created` means in the context of an image, outside of the source (which, ironically, you sourced). Thanks.

Comment: @Jack_Hu I agree. I see in the source "Created timestamp when image was created".

Comment: Please note that for command to work, spaces in the template should be removed like so: `{{.Created}}`

Comment: @AleksandrErokhin Good point, thank you. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Note that the value in {{.Created}} takes into account the availability of caches to build the image. If I add a file to the context today, and rebuild, {{.Created}} will be updated. If tomorrow I decide to remove the file, and rebuild, {{.Created}} will be set back to the time of the older build, if it's still available in the cache.

Comment: @DaveBaird Good point. This is more the date of the last used cache then?

Comment: @VonC It seems to be. I was trying to use {{.Created}} to timestamp a file to trigger Makefile actions whenever a docker image is modified, but if the modification takes you back to a previous cache, the timestamp went backwards instead of forwards which screwed up my build process.